# Subviews of UITableViewCell are not visible while reordering

Tags: ios, uitableview, subview

When I reorder my UITableViewCells, the Subviews of the Cell are not visible while dragging...I get always the same result, whether I add the Subviews programmatically in a UITableViewCell Subclass or in Storyboard...

Is there a possibility to see the real UITableViewCell with Subviews while dragging?

[image]

Comment: Provide the code you tried for this.

Comment: I have no special code for this problem because it happens in every conceivable constellation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution by my self...

For some reason the mysterious reordering animation from Apple cant capture simple UIViews, but with UIImageViews, UIButtons and UILabels as Subviews of the custom TableViewCell, the animation works like expected...creepy!